# Symfony2 division project into bundles

Tags: symfony

I am new in Symfony2 and I am starting new project where will be articles, blogs with posts, polls, etc. The application will have administration part.

I would like to know how much should be the application divided into the bundles. What are the best practices.

Should I make:

- One bundle with all logic (public and private).
- Public bundle for whole portal and administration bundle for private part.
- Article bundle, Blog bundle, Poll bundle, etc. and Administration bundle (maybe divided on AdminArticle bundle, AdminBlog bundle,...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you divide application into logical bundles, in other words, which is your third option.
For example: Main Bundle, Article bundle, Blog bundle, Poll bundle, and AdminBundle

In the Main Bundle, you can make global methods, homepage, twig extensions etc.